# concatenate strings in C including numbers array

Tags: c, string-concatenation

I need to write a short C program as school homework which should concatenate two strings to one. I wrote the following code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char str1[11], str2[11], new_str[21];
    
    fgets(str1, sizeof(str1), stdin);
    
    fgets(str2, sizeof(str2), stdin);

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (str1[i] != '\n' && str1[i] != '\0') {
        new_str[i] = str1[i];
        i++;
    }
    while (str2[j] != '\n') {
        new_str[i+j] = str2[j];
        j++;
    }
    new_str[i+j] = '\0';
    printf("%s", new_str);

    return 0;
}
```

But one of the tests requires concatenate:

```
abcdefghij
0123456789
```

into: `abcdefghij0123456789`

and I can't understand why my code doesn't work for the numbers array.

any help?

BTW- I CANT USE `<string.h>` functions

Comment: What is the output you get from your code?

Comment: The string buffers are too small. You show inputs of 10 characters, which will need 2 more array elements: the newline and the string terminator. The first input's newline remains in the input buffer, and that is all the second input will read. In general, don't use the *smallest* buffer you think you need, but the *largest* buffer you can justify.

Comment: You seem to understand that fgets may leave a \n in the read data but you never discarded the `\n`. Allocate larger buffers and discard `\n` from the input.

Comment: If you're not allowed to use the functions from `string.h`, write your own and call them `mystrcpy`, etc. Many of those functions like `strcpy`, `strcat`, `strcmp` are very simple.

Comment: This is an ideal opportunity to learn [how to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @NIRAY  Aside: Consider loop `while (str2[j] != '\n') {`, what happens when `str2[]` does not contain a `'\n'`?

Answer (score 3):

`char str1[11]` is too short to store the 11-character strings `abcdefghij\n` for the first line, so reading is stopped before reading whole line and the `\n`for the first line is read to `str2`.

Allocate enough size to have it work correctly.

Another approach that should work for any length of lines is printing characters read except for newline characters until reading two newline characters.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int c;
    int nlcnt = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            nlcnt++;
            if (nlcnt >= 2) break;
        } else {
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help! works now.

Comment: @NIRAY you thank people by clicking the green checkmark at the upper-left of their answer.

Comment: MikeCAT, Depending on buffering mode _Another approach_ prints output interlaced with input, unlike OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand following which will work:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char str1[11], str2[11], new_str[21];
    
    fgets(str1, sizeof(str1), stdin);
    getchar(); // read \n from string
    fgets(str2, sizeof(str2), stdin);

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (!(str1[i] == '\n' || str1[i] == '\0')) {
        new_str[i] = str1[i];
        i++;
    }
    while (!(str2[j] == '\n' || str2[j] == '\0')) {
        new_str[i+j] = str2[j];
        j++;
    }
    new_str[i+j] = '\0';
    printf("%s", new_str);

    return 0;
}
```

I am not explaining the code. If you cannot understand leave me a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to understand that fgets may leave a \n in the read data but you never discarded the `\n`. Allocate larger buffers and discard `\n` from the input.

If you execute this directly after the fgets calls you'll spot the problem:

```
for(int i=0; str1[i]!='\0'; i++)
  printf("%c = %d\n", str1[i], str1[i]);
for(int i=0; str2[i]!='\0'; i++)
  printf("%c = %d\n", str2[i], str2[i]);
```

Output:

```
a = 97
b = 98
c = 99
d = 100
e = 101
f = 102
g = 103
h = 104
i = 105
j = 106

 = 10
```

The first string didn't have enough space to save both `\n` and `\0` so it left `\n` in `stdin` for the next poor soul that comes along. Which in your case was `fgets(str2, sizeof(str2), stdin);`.

Quick fix:

```
char str1[12], str2[12], new_str[21];

fgets(str1, sizeof(str1), stdin);
str1[strlen(str1)-1] = '\0';

fgets(str2, sizeof(str2), stdin);
str2[strlen(str2)-1] = '\0';
```

Comment: Former part looks good, but your "Quick fix" is bad because 1. `strlen` is used while stated as "I CANT USE `<string.h>` functions" 2. `str2[strlen(str2)-1] = '\0';` may erase `'\n'` and make the loop `while (str2[j] != '\n')` run infinitely (until invoking *undefined behavior* by reading out-of-range)

Comment: @MikeCAT I couldn't care less about artificial requirements for some homework assignment. Implementing strlen manually isn't hard even for beginners.